# Incorrect resizing of SVG shape in Processing?

Tags: svg, processing

I have an SVG file, of which I've taken a snippet as a test file; the test file can be found here: [tester1.svg](https://cdn.mediacru.sh/gGSag_EWhWwp.svg), and I've also pasted it below. Note that its content stretches nearly symmetrically from left to right - this is how `evince` renders it:

[image: tester1_evince.png]

This tester, as well as the original SVG file, display the same problem - if I run this Processing MWE code (say, `test.pde`):

```java
PShape s;
int sz=90;
void setup() {
  size(600, 600); // size(600, 600, P2D);
  s = loadShape("tester1.svg");
  smooth();
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  stroke(150);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(100,100);
  rotate(0.6);
  shapeMode(CENTER);
  shape(s, 0, 0, sz, sz);
  // draw "bounding box" rectangle
  noFill();
  rectMode(CENTER);
  rect( 0, 0, sz, sz );
  popMatrix();
}
```

... then I get this as output:

[image: tester1_processing]

... that is - the SVG shape is read fine, rotated fine - but it doesn't quite scale to the requested size `sz`, as shown by the bounding box rectangle.

Does anyone have any idea why it happens - and how to have the shape scale fully?

Note that:

- I've tried some simple shapes (e.g. circle, and making the document bounds match the circle size) made in Inkscape, and they didn't demonstrate this problem
- If I use `size(600, 600, P2D);` with the sketch and SVG above, then the output is completely messed up (random red all over); but if I use the same with the original SVG and a slightly different sketch, then the bounding matches fine with `P2D` (but not without).

Could be some SVG directive is needed, but I don't know the SVG spec, nor Processing, in that much detail. Here is `tester1.svg`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="809pt" height="669pt" viewBox="0 0 809 669" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g id="#ffffffff">
</g>
<g id="#881d1dff">
<path fill="#d50f10" opacity="1.00" d=" M 779.88 266.03 C 786.38 264.30 794.20 264.63 799.10 259.31 C 796.10 268.46 791.88 277.13 787.63 285.75 C 784.30 291.72 781.27 297.91 777.16 303.41 C 683.44 303.32 589.72 303.42 496.00 303.36 C 489.66 303.27 483.33 303.79 477.00 303.78 C 431.99 303.71 386.98 303.78 341.98 303.75 C 328.33 303.12 314.66 303.46 301.00 303.37 C 246.67 303.37 192.33 303.38 138.00 303.38 C 103.01 303.28 68.01 303.57 33.03 303.23 C 30.80 299.69 28.66 296.11 26.62 292.46 C 23.10 286.12 19.03 279.96 17.07 272.90 C 23.29 272.92 29.53 272.77 35.74 273.38 C 74.86 276.57 113.91 280.63 153.04 283.73 C 168.01 284.45 183.03 283.68 197.99 284.73 C 218.32 285.15 238.66 284.86 258.99 284.97 C 267.35 285.08 275.65 283.81 284.00 283.85 C 309.66 283.95 335.33 283.83 361.00 283.92 C 372.36 283.94 383.64 282.38 394.99 282.06 C 402.34 281.86 409.65 280.90 417.00 280.85 C 506.34 280.87 595.67 280.85 685.00 280.86 C 689.93 280.82 694.88 281.19 699.80 280.64 C 705.34 279.98 709.19 275.47 714.07 273.23 C 719.45 270.76 725.26 269.24 731.13 268.51 C 747.35 267.23 763.91 270.07 779.88 266.03 Z" />
</g>
<g id="#cfbbbbff">
<path fill="#cfbbbb" opacity="1.00" d=" M 556.18 330.28 C 559.51 330.43 554.63 333.27 556.18 330.28 Z" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I tried this by myself and had the same issue. Your svg file seems to be the source of the problem. I had different results for this svg using different programs to view.

Comment: If you use this <svg> body instead (single diagonal line) it works:
<svg height="500" width="500">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="500" y2="500" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
</svg>